# Pro karaoke for ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I do a show and use Compuhost which is not compatible with Linux. Is there a comparable program for ubuntu?  Compuhost is a professional karaoke program.

Answer (score 0):

**Lives** can be used as a Primary VJ application.

Can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install lives
```